# Aurelia component binding

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I'm new to this framework and I was wondering whether or not there's a component binding that allows you to specify the component to be used on a regular HTML element and not a custom one.

Let's say we have a `Message` component. Would it be possible to use it as:

```
<div component="message"></div>
```

instead of

```
<message></message>
```

Knockout.js supports this for their components: [The "component" binding.](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-binding.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yep! You can use the `as-element` custom attribute to do this.

**Here's an example: https://gist.run?id=5fc98df81dff7eec2868ea918f6342fb**

**app.html**

```html
<template>
   <require from="./message"></require>

   <message say="Say"></message>

   <div as-element="message" say.bind="what"></div>
</template>
```

**app.js**

```js
export class App {
  what = 'What!'
}
```

**message.html**

```html
<template>
  <h1>${say}</h1>
</template>
```

**message.js**

```js
import {bindable} from 'aurelia-framework';

export class MessageCustomElement {
  @bindable say = '';
}
```

**rendered**

[image]